# Java define class members by a final array

Tags: java, class, class-members

I have an array which contains some definitions which are used in the program:

```
final String[] names = new String[]{"familyNames", "givenNames", "middleNames", "nickNames", "additionalNames", ..., ..., ..., ...}; // Lots of definitions
```

And now I need to create a new class with these definitions:

```
public class Person {
  final private String id;
  final private String familyNames;
  final private String givenNames;
  final private String middleNames;
  final private String nickNames;
  final private String additionalNames;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ... // Very long list
}
```

Is it possible to define this class by that array? Something like:

```
public class Person {
  final private String id;
  final private .... names...
  public int compareTo(...) {...}
}
```

This `Person` class should support sort by multi fields, e.g. first by given name, then by family name, etc.

Comment: Are you only storing strings, or will there be other types mixed in, which you need to access _as that type_ (ie, perform math on an integer/float, get the next month from a date, etc)?  For sorting, you'll need to implement `Comparable`, using @Juned's answer.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid a long list of class member variables, you may use a map of attributes as mentioned here:

```
Map<String,String> attributesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

"familyNames", "givenNames", "middleNames", "nickNames", "additionalNames", etc should be used as keys.

Comment: Probably the better option, for anyone who isn't building a whatever-to-Java compiler... :)

Comment: Just updated my question. The requirement is to sort `Person` objects by multi-fields. Looks like I need to add `CompareTo()` to the class, but not sure how to do it base on map?

Answer (score 0):

You could define it in a class `Person` by taking the attributesMap in a static factory method.

```
public class Person {
  final private String id;
  final private Name name;
  ...
  public static Person fromAttributesMap(Map<String, String> attributesMap) {
      Person person = new Person();
      person.id = attributesMap.get("id");
      ...
  }
}
```

But do keep related attributes together in their own classes. For eg; you could club `familyName`, `givenName`, `nickName`, etc. in a `Name` class:

```
class Name {
  final private String familyName;
  final private String givenName;
  final private String middleName;
}
```

I'm not in full agreement to the map approach. Infact, there is a code smell around the same - it is called "Primitive obsession"

You could also sort a `List<Person>`, for example by the family name:

```
public static Comparator<Person> FamilyNameComparator 
                      = new Comparator<Person>() {

    public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {


      //ascending order
      return person1.getFamilyName().compareTo(person2.getFamilyName());
    }

};
```

and then calling:

```
Arrays.sort(persons, Person.FamilyNameComparator);
```

You could also sort by multiple fields. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969270/java-comparator-for-multi-column-sorting) question on SO.

Comment: How is the program supposed to know that fields X, Y, Z... from the array are actually in a sub-object?  How is this stuff supposed to be auto-generated as the question seems to be asking?

Comment: By implementing an appropriate constructor, or a factory method like "fromAttributeMap()". I'll probably update my answer; but I still stand by my reservations against using a hashmap directly.

Comment: @cHao I am not absolutely sure if the OP wanted to model adhoc/random strings in the "names" array. I'll probably update my answer (and talk about using a factory method).