# Alphanumeric sorting for list of objects in java

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Please help me out to sort the list of objects given below

```
Input: List list = [ob1,ob2,ob3,ob4] 
        ob1 = ["BH11", "val2", "val3"];
        ob2 = ["BH1", "val4", "val5"];
        ob3 = ["BH12", "val6", "val7"];
        ob4 = ["BH2", "val8", "val9"];
```

After sorting based upon values at index 0 of each object i.e. `BH11, BH1` etc.
Expected output : `sortedList = [ob2,ob4,ob1,ob3]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java comparator for multi-column sorting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969270/java-comparator-for-multi-column-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Collection.sort(list, (a,b)->{return a[0].compareTo(b[0])});
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `Comparable` interface in the object class and override the `compareTo()` method to your liking.  You can then use `sort`

See java documentation here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html